# Run a command as remote user ID in a web server

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat7, remote-access, kerberos-delegation

I have a web application running on Tomcat7 and apache Httpd server. I have a use case to run  a command as remote or client user on the web server whose user account is different from remote user accounts. Currently I am handing this requirement by running web server as root user and allowing root user to sudo as remote user for executing the commands on server side.

Please let me know if you have any better and secure ways to handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: Running your webserver as root is dangerous. Look into using the `sudoers` file and allowing a standard account to execute the commands you need as a different user.

Comment: Thanks for update! I am looking for ways without doing sudo by server.